# JS How to export g tag from SVG as an other SVG with new viewBox and position

Tags: javascript, svg

I have SVG like this. Where my path drown in the way that it's out of SVG viewBox.

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2560 1440" width="2560" height="1440"><g id="_x3C_Group_x3E__pa-svg">
        <path id="Fork_SHadow" style="opacity:0.25;fill:#231F20;" d="M1091.0469,267.8867l0.0001-0.0009l10.5656-71.3811l4.0033,0.4644    l75.0217-503.2216c2.2681-15.2133-3.4084-30.5287-15.0432-40.5888c-13.9468-12.059-33.8468-14.3676-50.1838-5.8222v0.0002    c-1.7036,0.8911-3.3354,1.8835-4.8894,2.9679c-10.0999,7.0483-16.9041,17.9816-18.7178,30.2461    c-0.1396,0.9434-0.2495,1.8947-0.3293,2.8527l-42.1799,507.0316l4.0034,0.4644l-6.0574,71.9041v0.0003l-1.2817,15.2183    c-1.4341,10.5262-4.5144,21.322-12.0391,27.0696c-3.5157,2.6857-7.6854,4.2604-11.5655,6.3386    c-30.9933,16.5999-37.9016,61.0826-38.5026,93.533l-11.103,216.7082c-0.2063,4.0217,5.6655,4.7028,6.3859,0.7408l36.3053-199.7384    c0.2012-1.1075,1.8425-0.9171,1.7848,0.207l-10.3872,202.7453c-0.2062,4.0217,5.6656,4.7028,6.3859,0.7408l36.3052-199.7384    c0.2013-1.1075,1.8424-0.9171,1.7848,0.207l-10.3875,202.7452c-0.2059,4.0217,5.6659,4.7029,6.386,0.7408l36.3054-199.7384    c0.2013-1.1075,1.8425-0.9171,1.7849,0.207l-10.3876,202.7452c-0.2062,4.022,5.6659,4.7032,6.3859,0.7408l38.8057-213.4943    c6.8442-31.7261,10.3033-76.6089-16.0664-99.8636c-3.301-2.9113-6.9994-5.3989-9.8071-8.8181    c-6.0078-7.317-6.5356-18.5297-5.5222-29.103L1091.0469,267.8867z"/>

            <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow:visible;" width="870" height="4146" id="Fork" xlink:href="<value is too large to edit>" transform="matrix(0.24 0 0 0.24 937.44 -535.44)">
        </image>
    </g></svg>
```

I want to change my SVG viewBox and content using JavaScript to have SVG like bellow.
Smaller viewBox to fit with g tag. And changed path coordinates.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 243.68918 1172.36385">
          <g id="_Group_pa-svg" data-name="&lt;Group&gt; pa-svg">
            <path id="Fork_SHadow" data-name="Fork SHadow" d="M153.60692,803.3267l.00012-.00086,10.56555-71.3811,4.00329.46441L243.19761,229.1876a44.90454,44.90454,0,0,0-65.227-46.411v.00024a44.89285,44.89285,0,0,0-23.60718,33.214q-.20946,1.41513-.32934,2.85272L111.85411,725.87516l4.00342.46441-6.05738,71.90412v.0003l-1.28174,15.21826c-1.43408,10.52625-4.5144,21.322-12.03906,27.06958-3.51575,2.68567-7.68542,4.26044-11.56555,6.33863-30.99329,16.59985-37.90161,61.08264-38.50256,93.533l-11.103,216.70813a3.221,3.221,0,0,0,6.38586.74084l36.3053-199.7384a.90023.90023,0,0,1,1.78479.207L69.397,1161.06632a3.221,3.221,0,0,0,6.38587.74084l36.3053-199.7384a.90023.90023,0,0,1,1.78479.207L103.48546,1165.021a3.22107,3.22107,0,0,0,6.386.74085l36.30542-199.73835a.9003.9003,0,0,1,1.78491.207L137.5742,1168.97568a3.221,3.221,0,0,0,6.38586.74085l38.80567-213.49427c6.84424-31.72607,10.30334-76.60894-16.06641-99.86364-3.301-2.91132-6.99939-5.39887-9.80713-8.81812-6.00781-7.317-6.53564-18.52966-5.52221-29.103Z" style="fill: #231f20;opacity: 0.25"/>
            <image id="Fork" width="870" height="4146" transform="scale(0.24)" xlink:href="<value is too large to edit>"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: You can access to `svg` tag like to any other  html tag. For example with the tag name:  `document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]`. For changing the viewBox attribute you can use `setAttribute` function. For example `document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 200 200')`

Comment: But how can I change the path command to have `M153.60692,803.3267` instead of `M1091.0469,267.8867`
I mean transfer `g` tag and its content to 0,0 point of viewBox.

Comment: You can get the path: `var path = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].getElementById("Fork_SHadow").getAttribute("d")`. Then manipulate the string: `var newPath = path.replace("M1091.0469,267.8867", "M153.60692,803.3267")` and for the last using the `setAttribute` function like the previous example `document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].getElementById("Fork_SHadow").setAttribute("d", newPath)`